# Texmaker freezes when iterating over an array and plotting with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots, texmaker, arrays, loops

I have written a latex piece that iterates over two arrays and creates a plot for each entry of the array. However, my Texmaker gets surprised and freezes (I just gets fully processing power of my CPU -- like an infinite loop).

Each section of the code makes sense syntactically, but I am wondering if it makes sense in latex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{arrayjob}


\begin{document}

%%%%% This is the template for my plots
\newcommand{\plotprh}[3] {
\subfigure[$\ell=#1$]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=5cm, 
        width=6cm,
        xlabel={$k'$},
        ylabel={Percent (\%)},
        legend pos=north west,
        legend cell align=left,
        ylabel style={at={(0.05,0.5)},font=\small},
        xlabel style={at={(0.5,0.04)},font=\small},
        legend style={at={(0.04,0.05)},anchor=south west, nodes={scale=0.8, transform shape},font=\small,}
    ]
    \addplot[]
        coordinates { % Precision
        #2
        };
    \addplot[]
        coordinates { % Recall
        #3
        };
        \legend{Precision, Recall}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  }

%%%%% Here is the data that I need which I put in two arrays
\newarray\recalls
\readarray{recalls}{ (1, 9.600000e-01) (2, 9.200000e-01) (3, 0.000000e+00) (4, 0.000000e+00) & (1, 9.600000e-01) (2, 9.600000e-01) (3, 0.000000e+00) (4, 0.000000e+00) }
\newarray\precisions
\readarray{precisions}{ (1, 8.099681e-01) (2, 7.699681e-01) (3, 0.000000e+00) (4, 0.000000e+00) & (1, 8.099681e-01) (2, 8.099681e-01) (3, 0.000000e+00) (4, 0.000000e+00) }

%%%%%% Here is how I try to plot it
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \foreach \index in {1, ..., 2}
    {%
        \plotprh{\index}{\precisions(\index)}{\recalls(\index)}
    }%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: for `arrayjob`, you need to put `&` between each entry.

Comment: @RunarTrollet actually there is `&` between each array entry. It means that array entries have spaces, but they are separated with `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** I am not really sure what output you are expecting here.

The documentation for `arrayjob` under `\readarray` (currently page 3) specifies that one should use `&` between each entry in the array.

Note that you can always locate the documentation using the command-line/terminal by writing `texdoc arrayjob`, and that works for any package. The documentation is also available at http://ctan.org/pkg/arrayjob

In the code below, I have not used `arrayjob`, although you could probably use it, there are other ways to create arrays without using an extra package. Since you are already loading `tikz` through `pgfplots`, I suggest just using the syntax described there. Also, your data points become a little easier to read if you add line breaks between every entry. I have here combined your two arrays into one for ease of use.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%%%%% This is the template for my plots
\newcommand{\plotprh}[3] {
\subfigure[$\ell=#1$]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        height=5cm, 
        width=6cm,
        xlabel={$k'$},
        ylabel={Percent (\%)},
        legend pos=north west,
        legend cell align=left,
        ylabel style={at={(0.05,0.5)},font=\small},
        xlabel style={at={(0.5,0.04)},font=\small},
        legend style={at={(0.04,0.05)},anchor=south west, nodes={scale=0.8, transform shape},font=\small,}
    ]
    \addplot
        coordinates { % Precision
        #2
        };
    \addplot
        coordinates { % Recall
        #3
        };
        %   \legend{Precision, Recall}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
  }

\def\plotData{%
    {(1,9.600000e-01)}/{(1,8.099681e-01)},%
    {(2,9.200000e-01)}/{(2,0.000000e+00)},%
    {(3,0.000000e+00)}/{(3,0.000000e+00)},%
    {(4,0.000000e+00)}/{(4,0.000000e+00)}%
    }

\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \foreach \recall/\precision  [count=\i] in \plotData
    {%
        \plotprh{\i}{\precision}{\recall}%
    }%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know what was the magic, as my code also had `&` delimiters, but I know this one works perfectly.